# Overall Ranking of Performance Based on Multiple Factors

Tags: ranking

I am currently trying to rank the overall effectiveness of counselors based on  5 factors. All the factors are rates because each counselor works a varying number of hours. Additionally all factors are weighted equally.

The suggested way to rank them has been to rank the counselors in each category and then average the rankings, but the concern is that doing this wont account for differences within categories. For example in one category the highest ranking counselor may only be slightly above the second highest, but in another category they may be substantially ahead of the second highest, so just averaging ranking would not take this into account. Is there a better way of creating an overall ranking.

The data is below:

```
              Factor  Factor   Factor   Factor  Factor
                 1       2       3        4      5
Counselor A:     0.19,   46%,    0.11,    1.88,  51%

Counselor B:     0.22,   49%,    0.17,    2.18,  47%

Counselor C:     0.31,   78%,    0.19,    2.53,  66%

Counselor D:     0.25,   54%,    0.09,    2.58,  81%

Counselor E:     0.21,   39%,    0.16,    1.60,  50%

Counselor F:     0.20,   55%,    0.18,    2.00,  47%

Counselor G:     0.36,   64%,    0.25,    2.36,  65%
```

Factors:

1. Outcomes Produced Per Client
2. Retention of Clients after One Appointment
3. Appointments Per Hour
4. Average Appointments Per Client
5. Appointment Show Rate

Comment: hey, did you find solution to this problem?? I am also facing similar issue..